# dynamic array in c

Tags: c, pointers

I want after I do some calculation create an array in **C** would  u please help me?

```
int len_arr = (sizeof inputs)/(sizeof inputs[0]);
int half_arr = len_arr / 2;
if(len_arr%2 != 0)
    half_arr++;

int m[half_arr][half_arr];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `malloc` to allocate your 2-dimensional array.

Look at this [LINK](http://c-faq.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx9b.html) for a good explanation.

---

**EDIT:**

Starting from the code at the given link, I've written a piece of code that should work.

Some differences from James' code:

- declaration of `m` at the top of the code block
- conversion from the return type of malloc (void *) to the correct one
- memory deallocation at the end
- it's a complete code, that **must** work :P

---

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ()
{

    // just an example of inputs...
    int inputs[3][7];

    // your code
    int i;
    int **m;
    int len_arr = (sizeof inputs)/(sizeof inputs[0]); 
    int half_arr = len_arr / 2; 
    if(len_arr%2 != 0)     
        half_arr++;  

    // allocation of the array
    m = (int **)malloc(half_arr * sizeof(int *));
    for(i = 0; i < half_arr; i++)
        m[i] = (int *)malloc(half_arr * sizeof(int));

    // use the array as you like...
    // ...

    // let's release the allocated memory properly
    for(i = 0; i < half_arr; i++)
        free(m[i]);
    free(m);

}
```

Comment: Oh, you accepted my answer before my edit :P Anyway, have a look at it if you want ;)

Comment: yes, because your link was so interesting for me & it was help me in a minute

Answer (score 4):

I'm assuming you wish to create a matrix with row/column size of `half_arr`.

```
int i;
int len_arr = (sizeof inputs)/(sizeof inputs[0]); 
int half_arr = len_arr / 2; 
if(len_arr%2 != 0)     
    half_arr++;  

int **m = malloc(half_arr * sizeof(int));

for (i = 0; i < half_arr; i++)
    *m = malloc(half_arr * sizeof(int));
```

You should then be able to access `m` using `m[row][column]` or `m[column][row]`.

Comment: then he has to do another loop like that freeing all that memory

Comment: @BlackBear: Yes, he does.  If he wishes to use `m[][]` syntax though it is needed.

Comment: `int m**` that a new type?  :)

Comment: Compiling...
main.c
C:\OBA_VTS\SVD_Enhancement\main.c(25) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
C:\OBA_VTS\SVD_Enhancement\main.c(28) : error C2065: 'm' : undeclared identifier
C:\OBA_VTS\SVD_Enhancement\main.c(28) : error C2100: illegal indirection
C:\OBA_VTS\SVD_Enhancement\main.c(28) : warning C4013: 'malloc' undefined; assuming extern returning int
C:\OBA_VTS\SVD_Enhancement\main.c(46) : error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

Comment: @James: no, it's not - the C language supports variable-length arrays; if rima uses MSVC as a compiler (which basically only supports C90), I strongly suggest using C++ instead or switching to MinGW

Comment: @rima: you need `#include <stdlib.h>` at the top

Comment: @digEmall : same problem is still there

Answer (score -1):

Your code is valid C99. You might want to use a compiler which supports newer revisions of the C language.

On Windows, I'd go with the [MinGW edition of gcc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/). If you're stuck with MSVC, I suggest using C++ instead: the standard container types will make your life less painful.